# sorting big data in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, bigdata

I have energy data with more than 25 million rows and 3 columns, the data looks like

[meter Id         Date+time            Load
    1000            19506                 .5
    1000            19501                 .5
     .                 .                   .
    1001            19500                 .6
     .                 .                    .
    .                  .                    .
   1999              19509                 .4
    .                  .                      .
    1999              73048                   .4]

I require to sort this data such that for each meter ID i.e. 1000-1999 (all 1000 meters) i get load arranged in a time series. The first three digit of time code show the day whereas the last two digits range from 0-48 showing 24 hours every half hours. I can sort the data according to meter ID but this does not arrange it according to time series. I am struggling to find a solution to find a technique to auto arrange the data such that it presents something like this;

meter ID 1000
[19501   19502 ..........................   73048
  .5        1.5............................  2.5]
and so on for all meter IDs. 
It is easy to solve in excel using filters, however given the amount of data, excel is not able to open this file. 
Any recommendation.

Comment: Formatting your question would help. Why don't you create a matrix for each meter and sort that by time?

Answer (score 0):

Use the matlab `sortrows` function.

```
data = [ 1000 19506 .5;
         1999 73048 .4;
         1000 19501 .5;
         1999 19509 .4;
         1001 19500 .6 ];
datSorted = sortrows(data, [ 1 2 ]); % sort by column 1 (meterID) then column 2 (Date+time)
```